# Python Plotly Dash Is there a way to use Css files outside the assets folder? / Have multiple assets folders

Tags: python, css, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Hi guys so I have been working on quite a big project and it's really messy to put all the CSS files inside one folder when my project is divided into a lot of folders for example:

```
-- assets # folder
-- components # folder
  -- Header # folder
    -- Buttons.py
    -- Title.py
    -- DateDropdown.py
  -- Body # folder
    -- Pages # folder
       -- page1.py
       -- page2.py
  -- SideNavBar # folder
  -- Footer # folder
-- app.py
```

And it goes on and on to different components, now I am searching for a solution like The way we work with CSS in react, put the CSS of the files that use it in the same folder import the CSS, and use it. or open an assets folder for each big component like header, footer, side navbar, and so on...

Thanks for taking your time reading! if you have an idea please do share it!

Example: (Update)
I have a folder tree that goes like this:

```
-- mainDash.py # the app is initiated here
-- app.py # The app layout is initiated here
-- components # Folder
    -- header.css
    -- Header.py # The header HTML
```

The code of the header python:

```
import dash_html_components as html

header = html.Div(
    id='Header', 
    children=[
        html.Link(
            rel='stylesheet',
            href='/components/header.css'
        ),
        html.Div("Medical Cost Personal")
    ]
)
```

The code of the header CSS:

```
#header {
    flex: 1;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

The code of the app initiation:

```
import dash
external_stylesheets = ['/components/header.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
```

Tried the external_stylesheets way and the HTML link way both didn't work any idea why?

Comment: Because you are missing the second step : the routing. See my answer/comments below.

Comment: @EricLavault
I still don't get how to use it am I supposed to have a folder named res and switch the <path:filepath> to the path of the file? how am I supposed to use this routing to add all the CSS files I have to the list?

Comment: No, `/res/<path:filepath>` matches _request_ path (relative to the app base url) beginning with `/res/`, like for example `/res/any/component/you/want.css`, so when the route callback is invoked, it receives (in this example) the argument filepath=`any/component/you/want.css`, and then returns `flask.send_from_directory('./', filepath)`, which literally means send the content of the file `any/component/you/want.css` relative to the dir. `'./' (the cwd of your app), not `res/`. Again, 'res/' is just a routing option, not mandatory, for ensuring your callback handles only _res/ources_ requests.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to include the stylesheets, there are two possibilities (one does not exclude the other) :

- Include css files as `external_stylesheets`, so that they are loaded within the `<head>` tag along with other stylesheets, eg. :

  ```python
  CSS = [
      'https://cdn.example.min.css',               # an external file
      '/res/components/Header/assets/buttons.css',
      '/res/components/Header/assets/title.css',
      # ... other component styles ...
  ]

  app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=CSS)
  ```
- Include css files in the layout as Link components where you need them, eg. :

  ```python
  html.Div(id='Header', children=[
      html.Link(
          rel='stylesheet',
          href='/res/components/Header/assets/title.css'
      ),
      html.Div('The Header')
  ])
  ```

Once you have included the stylesheets, the second thing is to serve these files as static resources, which means doing some routing (otherwise Dash/Flask will serve html) :

```python
from flask import send_from_directory

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=CSS)
server = app.server

# ...

@server.route('/res/<path:filepath>')
def serve_res(filepath):
    return flask.send_from_directory('./', filepath)
```

You noticed I prepended urls with `res`, this is just to ease the route matching and is a bit more secure, you could use `static` or whatever (just don't use `assets`, it's reserved by Dash), or just filter for filepath ending with `.css`.

Comment: The first and second solutions do not work, plus the first solution doesn't really help, the point is finding a way to work in a cleaner way, adding all the CSS files path in one file bound to bring troubles and because I need to write them before I initiate the app I can't add them to the list before.
The second way is just way too messy, even if it worked I am searching for a solution that can give me a way to add a CSS file that would work for the entire app and not just one HTML component.

Comment: and the third solution it would be great if u could elaborate a bit more I can't seem to understand how it works or how to implement it.

Comment: @Matan I did not mention "_adding all the CSS files path in one file_", there is a big misunderstanding : _the first thing is to include the stylesheets_ (I proposed 2 options) **AND** _the second thing is to serve these files as static resources_. There is no third solution. Now for including css files, the first option is exactly what you are asking for : you can refer as many files as necessary in the 'external_stylesheets' array, just make the routing accordingly. Also Dash uses Flask server by default so I referred to it as an example. I edited the answer to prevent confusion.

Comment: For more info on `@server.route` you can refer to the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/).

Comment: The first solution doesn't work for me for some reason..
and again even if it did after I pass the external_stylesheets argument to the app I need a way to add more stylesheets after the app was initiated if that's not possible then I can't use the solution even if we find why it doesn't work for me now

Comment: Check the html output of your app, in the `<head>` section you should have a `<link rel="stylesheet">` tag for each file registered in external_stylesheets, if the routing is correct (check 404's) then it should work, if the tags are not present there might be a bug, on my side it works. _...a way to add more stylesheets after the app was initiated_, well this is another question, but it's possible.

Comment: https://ibb.co/dGYS9Wz
https://ibb.co/NL9863M
My code, doesn't work, anything looks wrong to you?
and could you please share a way to add more CSS after the app was initiated if you know how?

Comment: Update the post with the involved code, both stylesheets inclusion and routing.

Comment: updated the code to the post

Comment: @EricLavault : I used your example and applied css through routing. I can see <link href="/res/sidebar/style.css" rel="stylesheet">, but the styling is not yet applied. Do you have any complete example that i refer to?